# What is the purpose of using exec command

Tags: linux, bash

Here I don't understand what the following piece of code is trying to achieve, I did search
online for the use of exec but don't quite get the idea, could anyone please help to explain?

Code snippet:
`exec $(dirname "$0")/init.sh -l interface.mod -l instrument.mod -a postinit.mod -a async.mod "$@"`

Thanks.

Comment: exec allows you to execute a command that completely replaces the current process instead of running the command as a child process.

Comment: So what is the good of it? After the command became the main process, does it mean now the main process will take in any commands instead of /bin/bash? E.g, echo 1, then 1 will be passed to the main process. Is this the right understanding? Thanks.

Comment: If you wanted to replace your bash shell with zsh, then you could `exec /bin/zsh`. So you have the idea. If you want to do the same thing, but allow yourself to `exit` from `zsh` and be back in `bash` you could replace within a subshell, e.g. `(exec /bin/zsh)`

Comment: Right, I guess I get the basic idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exec` is a builtin command of the Bash shell which allows you to execute a command that completely replaces the current process, i.e., the current shell process is destroyed, and entirely replaced by the command you specify. It is useful when you want to run a command, but you don't want a bash shell to be the parent process. When you exec a command, it replaces bash entirely - no new process is forked, no new PID is created, and all memory controlled by bash is destroyed and overwritten. This can be useful if, for instance, you want to give a user restricted access to a certain command. If the command exits because of an error, the user will not be returned to the privileged shell that executed it. `exec` may also be used without any command, to redirect all output of the current shell to a file. Here is the definition from [man bash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html):

> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
> If command is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new  process
> is  created.  The arguments become the arguments to command.  If
> the -l option is supplied,  the  shell  places  a  dash  at  the
> beginning  of  the  zeroth  argument passed to command.  This is
> what login(1) does.  The -c option causes command to be executed
> with  an empty environment.  If -a is supplied, the shell passes
> name as the zeroth argument to the executed command.  If command
> cannot  be  executed  for  some  reason, a non-interactive shell
> exits, unless the exec fail shell option  is  enabled.   In  that
> case,  it returns failure.  An interactive shell returns failure
> if the file cannot be executed.  If command  is  not  specified,
> any  redirections  take  effect  in  the  current shell, and the
> return status is 0.  If there is a redirection error, the return
> status is 1.

Comment: `exec` is also often used as an optimization. If a shell script is going to run some other program *as the last thing it does*, running the other program without `exec` means the shell has to sit there waiting for the other process to finish, doing nothing useful. Using `exec` means the shell hands directly off to the other program, and there's no extra useless process hanging out taking up resources. This seems like it might be the reason it's used here.